# Unable to populate the creator field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate

I'm unable to populate my creator,
everything is fine but id is not showing up

```
var StorySchema = new Schema({
     creator: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
     content: String,
     created: { type: Date, deafult: Date.now }
   })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Story', StorySchema);
```

here's my second code

```
api.route('/')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        var story = new Story({
          creator: req.decoded.id,
          content: req.body.content
        });

        story.save(function (er) {
            if (er) {
              res.send(er);
              return;
            }
            res.json('User story is created');
        });

    })

    .get(function (req, res) {
        Story.find({ creator: req.decoded.id})
            .populate({ path: 'creator'}).exec(function (er, data) {
          res.json(data);
        });
    })
```

everything is fine except user object id isn't showing up

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the decoded string into a proper ObjectID:

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
api.route('/')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        var story = new Story({
          creator: new ObjectId(req.decoded.id),
          content: req.body.content
        });

        story.save(function (er) {
            if (er) {
              res.send(er);
              return;
            }
            res.json('User story is created');
        });

    });
```

Comment: now it's not working even now I'm unable to get new story

Comment: no there's nothing , just creator isn't showing on returning json else is showing on without any error

Comment: So you're getting the response that the user story was created?

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this in order to convert your string to a valid mongo objectId

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
_id = new ObjectID(_id);
```